# Can't run C++17 parallel algorithms with GCC on Linux

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, tbb

I want to run std algorithms using execution policies from C++17 using GCC9.3.

I've downloaded https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/releases/download/v2021.1.1/oneapi-tbb-2021.1.1-lin.tgz

But I'm getting an error that "task" class is not defined
Even on "hello world" example from https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-intelthreadbuilding/index.html

```
#include "tbb/tbb.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace tbb;
using namespace std;
 
class first_task : public task { 
    public: 
    task* execute( ) { 
       cout << "Hello World!\n";
       return NULL;
    }
};
 
int main( )
{ 
    task_scheduler_init init(task_scheduler_init::automatic);
    first_task& f1 = *new(tbb::task::allocate_root()) first_task( );
    tbb::task::spawn_root_and_wait(f1);
}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
test.cpp:55:32: error: expected class-name before '{' token
   55 | class first_task : public task {
      |                                ^
test.cpp:57:5: error: 'task' does not name a type
   57 |     task* execute( ) {
      |     ^~~~
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:65:5: error: 'task_scheduler_init' was not declared in this scope
   65 |     task_scheduler_init init(task_scheduler_init::automatic);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:66:38: error: 'allocate_root' is not a member of 'tbb::v1::task'
   66 |     first_task& f1 = *new(tbb::task::allocate_root()) first_task( );
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:67:16: error: 'spawn_root_and_wait' is not a member of 'tbb::v1::task'
   67 |     tbb::task::spawn_root_and_wait(f1);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm compiling: using the following command:

`g++  -I<path_to_tbb>/oneapi-tbb-2021.1.1/include/oneapi -I<path_to_tbb>/oneapi-tbb-2021.1.1/include/oneapi/tbb -I<path_to_tbb>/oneapi-tbb-2021.1.1/include  -L<path_to_tbb>/oneapi-tbb-2021.1.1/lib/intel64/gcc4.8/ test.cpp -o test`

running `source env/var.h` from <path_to_tbb> didn't help
Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: The first two include paths are not necessary.  Try the shorter command `g++ -I<path_to_tbb>/oneapi-tbb-2021.1.1/include  -L<path_to_tbb>/oneapi-tbb-2021.1.1/lib/intel64/gcc4.8/ test.cpp -o test`

Comment: Not sure what happens here and it seems not much relevant, but `gcc4.8` looks quite wrong to me, since libstdc++ in GCC >= 5 has ABI incompatibility to previous binaries by design (for C++11 conformance) unless it is configured specifically for the backward compatibility.

Comment: You need to link your app against TBB, that is, add `-ltbb` to the command line, see for example: https://solarianprogrammer.com/2019/05/09/cpp-17-stl-parallel-algorithms-gcc-intel-tbb-linux-macos/ However, you have compiler errors, too. Try to use option `-E` trhat only executes the preprocessor step and see the resulting file. Also, the line numbers on the error messge do not correspond to the source you've showed to us. .

Comment: If you are on Linux, check if your distribution comes with a package for tbb, for example on Debian-based distributions, `apt install libtbb-dev` might work. Then compile with `g++ test.cpp -o test $(pkg-config --libs --cflags tbb)`.

Comment: Hi, 
thank you for your comments.
@S.M. - I still have the same issue even with a shorter command

Comment: @FrankHB - that's the only lib version there is.

Comment: @zkoza - I tried it with the ltbb too, It is not even compiling

Comment: @G.Sliepen I'm on CentOS but don't have permissions to install packages. It's shared, not my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message I conclude that either the gcc or TBB implementation you use is sort of experimental. As you can see, gcc does find the TBB (no error on `#include tbb/tbb.h`), that's good! Then, the errors show that some functions you use are hidden inside the `tbb::v1` namespace. So you can either use `using namespace tbb::v1` or add `tbb::v1::` in front of all "unknown" names.

Then, in
https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Threading-Building/Unable-to-compile-TBB-program/td-p/1226663
they sey that `tbb::task` is depreciated. Please use a bit more modern TBB tutorial :-)

See also: https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/issues/243

Comment: Thank you very much. The example linked in your comment does compile. But original "tasks" error was coming from GCC execution policy header. not me using "task" directly.  
Should I use older version of TBB with GCC? What version works with GCC 9.3?

Comment: You should not use old examples! That's it, I suppose. Old examples on www pages of trusted companies are quite common these days, for the industry changes very quickly., One example is cmake, which has plenty of tutorials for beginners, but none of those I found teaches "modern cmake". The error came from gcc, this is possible, but its origin is definitely in TBB. Most likely anything that was depreciated was moved to `tbb::v1` namespace. Simply do not use these features, as they will soon be removed from TBB.

Comment: I didn't use those features. I added <execution> include. The code in GCC apparently uses task. I didn't find GCC/TBB compatibility matrix.

Comment: The code you've showed to us uses tasks explicitly. Next time show just the code you're interested in. Also, it is possible that when gcc 9.3 was released, TBB task was not depreciated. See also: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/tbb-revamp.html and the pdf therein.  I used TBB extensively in my last project, but we had one person dedicated to deal with all these compability issues and to write wrappers for them.